# versioned clientset for client-go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am read some code https://github.com/openshift/router/blob/master/pkg/router/controller/factory/factory.go.

In this go file, it references to 3 clientset, I have used standard K8s clientset - k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes, but I don't understand why many projects like to generate new clientset? Why standard K8s clientset doesn't provide enough API or functionalities? Could anybody give ideas or an example why some project wants to generate new clientset? What is it for?

```
    kclientset "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"

    projectclient "github.com/openshift/client-go/project/clientset/versioned/typed/project/v1"
    routeclientset "github.com/openshift/client-go/route/clientset/versioned"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't understand why many projects like to generate new clientset?

> projectclient "github.com/openshift/client-go/project/clientset/versioned/typed/project/v1"
> routeclientset "github.com/openshift/client-go/route/clientset/versioned"

Here the OpenShift project has decided to *extend* Kubernetes by creating its own [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). When creating a *custom resource*, you typically also create a [custom controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-controllers) - these two can be generated with e.g. [kubebuilder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder) and it is very handy to have a **generated client** for the new types. This can be seen in many different projects that create its own *custom resources*.

Comment: I know for custom resource, we use controller. My question is, there is standard K8s clientset, why they want to create new clientset such as routeclientset in the above.

Comment: because it is easier to do programming with a typed client than to hand-write http-requests. And the generated is specific to the _custom resource_.

Comment: I know currently many developers use Operator-SDK to manage CR, is the above way (generated) out of date?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Now these projects use a _generic client_ from controller-runtime, but this was not the case a few years ago. https://godoc.org/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client